# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6037]

Tags: laravel, redis

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6037] (View: C:\laragon\www\Project CRM\resources\views\users\index.blade.php)

keep getting the error in my laravel project , it only appears in my specific module of users and when i login with the user credentials , otherwise it does not affect my other modules of the code

my env file is

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=daybyday
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6037
```

any idea what is causing this error ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you have no Redis server listening?

Comment: so how do i solve this ?

Comment: If you intended to use Redis: Install it. If you didn't intend to use Redis: Figure out where you used it and don't use it. :)

Comment: that is exactly the problem , i don't intend to use redis but i get this error in my users module only , the other modules are working fine , i don't know how to solve this , could you please help me with that ?

Comment: We'd need to see that module then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redis server was not started and the port number was wrong in my env file